# Java sub list memory allocation

Tags: java, arraylist, parallel-processing, thread-safety

Java provides a `subList` function to get a view of the list between specified indices and is backed by the parent list meaning, any changes made to `subList` will reflect in the actual list. What I wish to know is whether these sublists get locked by the parent list if threads try to access them.

As an example, if I have a an `ArrayList` of 100 elements and I create 4 sublists each with 25 elements and 4 threads try to work in parallel on these sublists, will they work on their independent sublists in a truly parallel manner or will the first thread which gets executed, lock the backing arraylist?

If an arraylist is not locked by default, I am assuming the threads will run in parallel on the sublists without waiting for each other and if I programmatically ensure or rather the logic itself ensures that these threads never work on anything else other than their sublists then it will truly be parallel processing of the sublists, right?

```
executor.addTask(new Thread(doneSignal, parentList.subList(subListStart, subListEnd)));
```

The reason I ask is, I tried to loop over the sublists in parallel and noticed that it was substantially slower than not creating 4 threads and looping over the actual parent list.

Comment: What Java function do you mean?

Comment: List.subList(from, to)

Comment: `ArrayList` does no locking at all. How are these threads working on the sublists? Are they reading elements, or setting elements, deleting elements?

Comment: Don't write the code in comments, post the code to the question.

Comment: The threads, read and set values in the sublist. No deletion (as of now)

Comment: In that case you should have no problems. Read and set are not structural changes, so they can be done in parallel without a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Deletion won't work.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBoddington

Comment: The reason I ask is, I tried to loop over the sublists in parallel and noticed that it was substantially slower than not creating 4 threads and looping over the actual parent list.

Comment: That sounds like a much more difficult question. I'd ask a separate question, giving code for the 2 approaches, and asking what accounts for the difference in performance.

Comment: 100 elements sounds pretty small - how long does this work take? If you're doing "trivial" work, the overhead of creating the threads etc will dwarf any speed up you get in doing the processing in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the [Javadoc for `java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Of course, this applies to the `subList` method. So, no locking is done by the `ArrayList` itself; you need to do it yourself if you require it.

Comment: I see. I have edited my question with the concern I have, which seems to be contradicting what should ideally happen.

Answer (score 1):

> What I wish to know is whether these sublists get locked by the parent list if threads try to access them.

No, they won't.

> ... [w]ill they work on their independent sublists in a truly parallel manner

Yes.  (Unless there are other factors that are working against parallelism.)

> I tried to loop over the sublists in parallel and noticed that it was substantially slower than not creating 4 threads and looping over the actual parent list.

That could be down to other things.  For example, thread creation overheads, a thread pool that is too small, or trying to run multi-threaded code when there are too few cores.

Another possibility is that you are creating sublists of a synchronized list.  If you do that, when the sublist methods delegate operations to the parent list, those operations will all be locking the same list.  Note however it is the parent list that is responsible for this, not the sublists.